# How to disable other td if td in first is equal test?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I want to disable second or third `td` if value in first `td` is for example equal to `test`

My example table looks like this:

```
  <table id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_subElems7909_repSubElems_tblData">
    <tr>
      <td >John</td>
      <td ><input type="text"  name="lname" ></td>
      <td >Blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >John</td>
      <td ><input type="text"  name="lname" ></td>
      <td >Blah</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I tried with that jquery code to disable but didn't work.

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_subElems7909_repSubElems_tblData tr").each( function( index, val ){
    if($(this).find("td:first-child").text() == 'Test;') {
        $(this).find("td:last-child").prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

If I use hide method everything work fine by I want to use disable
Can someone explain hwy disable didint work in this case

Comment: _"Can someone explain hwy disable didint work in this case"_ - because you simply can't "disable" a table cell. Form input elements can be disabled - but that's not what you are accessing there.

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. What are you trying to achieve?  Give os proper examples please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot disable a table cell straightforwardly.

What you can do is based on your condition check apply a class to the row and then use `pointer-events: none;` CSS on that class

Working sample:

```js
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_subElems7909_repSubElems_tblData tr").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("td:first-child").text() == 'Test') {
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

```css
tr.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_subElems7909_repSubElems_tblData">
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname"></td>
    <td>Blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname"></td>
    <td>Blah</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks it works if I  change  $(this).find("td:last-child").addClass('disabled'); i can disabled td in my row